# Update Event with Fullcalendar in React

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

So I am trying to work with FullCalendar and I want to have the user be able to edit an event details, click update and I locally update the event and then push it up to the server. I have the following code, but the issue is when there are multiple changes, is calling the event callback multiple times. Is there a way I could do this just once to save on many API calls? Here is the code I have

```js
let currentEvent = calendarApi.getEventById(eventId);

currentEvent.setExtendedProp('notes', notes);
currentEvent.setExtendedProp('person', person);
```

Maybe there is a different method I am just not seeing in the docs?

Answer (score 2):

The undocumented [`mutate`](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/d23d0927d67b60fa31b7f9faeb05d097edf68dfa/packages/common/src/api/EventApi.ts#L209) method that's used to implement [`setExtendedProp`](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/d23d0927d67b60fa31b7f9faeb05d097edf68dfa/packages/common/src/api/EventApi.ts#L66) accepts an object that can have multiple properties. You could use it like this:

```
event.mutate({
  extendedProps: {
    notes: notes,
    person: person,
  },
})
```

or, using object property value shorthand:

```
event.mutate({extendedProps: {notes, person}})
```

I have absolutely no experience with fullcalender though, so use at your own risk!